# YouTube Data API authentication for public search (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, youtube-data-api, google-api-ruby-client

Our YouTube integration suddenly stopped working[1], so I started to port to the `google-api-client` gem version 0.9, but I can't find a way to search without authenticating a user. I just want to do a public search. Is that not possible anymore? All the samples still use v0.8 of the gem, which is basically a completely different library.

What I tried:

```
youtube = Google::Apis::YoutubeV3::YouTubeService.new
youtube.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    client_id:     CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    token_credential_uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token',
    authorization_uri:    'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
youtube.authorization.grant_type = 'client_credentials'
res = youtube.list_searches(:snippet, q: q, type: 'video')
```

Which results in:

> Missing authorization code.

[1] The old code now always says this, but why referrer for a server <-> server API call? And I don't see a form to configure IPs.

> There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.